# How to download Ruby Tk graphics library with Apple silicon chips

Tags: ruby, graphics, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to install Tk library following the installation guide from my online course. Here's what I've done so far:

A. Installed Ruby:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951)
```

B. Installed Homebrew:

```
brew -v
Homebrew 3.5.9
```

C. Installed RVM:

```
rvm help
Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.12
```

D. Tried installing ActiveTcl 8.5 from http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads but clicking the button does not download anything and just brings me to another website page:
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrEtW.png)

I'm not sure how essential is that step..

E. The course's guide than asks to run this command in the terminal:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.3 --with-tcl --with-tk
```

The error that I get:

```
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/dave/.rvm/log/1660564227_ruby-2.2.3/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

As you might guess, I'm very new to CS so I would appreciate your most "for-the-beginner" explanation of what should I do to install Tk library.
I'm using Macbook with M2 chip and Monterey OS.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working with Ruby 3.1.2 and `tcl-tk` 8.6.12 from Homebrew on my M1 MacBook Air running Monterey. The main hint that got me unstuck came from [this comment](https://github.com/ruby/tk/issues/21#issuecomment-704584662) on a similar issue from a couple of years ago.

Once I had `tcl-tk` installed through Homebrew, I installed the `tk` gem with the following set of switches:

```
gem install tk -- \
  --with-tcl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.12_1 \
  --with-tk-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.12_1 \
  --with-tcllib=tcl86 \
  --with-tklib=tk86 \
  --with-X11-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.1
```

There are a few pages out there which say that the `tk` gem doesn't work with `tcl-tk` 8.6.x, but so far I haven't had any issues.

Comment: save my day ~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory

You don't have permissions to write there because that directory is for system gems owned by root. Don't mess with that.

Never install gems into your system directory, except possibly inside a container. Use a Ruby version manager such as rvm, chruby, or rbenv instead to install *user* gems. You may also need Xcode command-line tools and Homebrew (or some other package manager) to install build dependencies.

Comment: Can you give a command line for reinstalling gem the right with rvm (which I have just installed)?